# Hive and JDK-9 issue

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm not able to install Hive with Java 9, and I get some errors. I visited this [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17632] link showing some issues. Why is this?

Comment: Tell us the *exact* errors you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found from that JIRA, JDK9 is not compatible for Hive, and the ticket is still open

You'll need separately install Java 8 and set up your Hive startup scripts to make sure it uses Java 8

Comment: I have tried this and it worked  ***Thank you***